# Is my proof using induction correct. $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq 5) 2^{n+3} < (n+1)!$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, induction

I'd appreciate if somebody could check whether my proof (mathematical induction) is correct.

$$(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq 5) 2^{n+3} < (n+1)!$$

(i) let $n=5$
$2^{5+3} = 2^{8} < (5+1)!=6!$

(ii) Let's assume that the statement is true for $k \in \mathbb{N}, k\geq 5$.

Our inductive hypothesis (IH) is that:
$2^{k+3} < (k+1)!$

We'll show that:
$2^{k+4} < (k+2)!$

$$2^{k+4} = 2.2^{k+3} < (IH)  2.(k+1)!$$

since $k\geq 5 \Rightarrow k+2\geq 7$ then...

$$ 2.(k+1)! < (k+2)(k+1)! = (k+2)!$$

By principle of mathemathical induction, we've shown that the statement applies for $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq 5$.

Is the second part correct? Im worried whether it's okay for me to use the fact that $k\geq 5 \Rightarrow k+2\geq 7$ then...

$$ 2.(k+1)! < (k+2)(k+1)! = (k+2)!$$

Comment: I don' t see any problem : $k+2\geq 7>2$ then $\color{red}{2<(k+2)}$ then $\color{red}{2}(k+1)!<\color{red}{(k+2)}(k+1)!$